# How to completely disable the navigation bar, but keep the NavigationView in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui, navigationbar, navigationview

I have a list in a NavigationView because I use the NavigationLink method to change between views, but I want to hide the navigation bar completely, which appears when I pull the list down. I have buttons in the area of the navigation bar that I need to press and I can't press them because the navigation bar is above them.

Answer (score 0):

you should use [navigationBarHidden](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/3338624-navigationbarhidden) modifier. here is an example:

```
var body: some View {
   NavigationView {
      VStack { // or whatever you want
         ...// your view
      }
      .navigationBarTitle("")
      .navigationBarHidden(true)
   }
 }
```

notice that you have to use `navigationBarHidden` for your child view, not for `NavigationView` itself, and setting `navigationBarTitle` seems like a hack, without setting a title, it doesn't work for me.